# UIImage with transparent rounded corners

Tags: iphone, uiimage, rounded-corners

I'm using following code to add rounded corners to my UIImage, but the problem is that the rounded corners are showing "white" area instead of transparent or "clear". What am i doing wrong here:

```
- (UIImage *)makeRoundCornerImageWithCornerWidth:(int)cornerWidth cornerHeight:(int)cornerHeight {
    UIImage * newImage = nil;

    if (self != nil)    {
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        int w = self.size.width;
        int h = self.size.height;

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        [self addRoundedRectToPath:context rect:rect width:cornerWidth height:cornerHeight];

        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextClip(context);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), self.CGImage);
        CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        CGContextRelease(context);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        newImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked] retain];
        CGImageRelease(imageMasked);

        [pool release];
    }

    return [newImage autorelease];
}


- (void)addRoundedRectToPath:(CGContextRef)context rect:(CGRect)rect width:(float)ovalWidth height:(float)ovalHeight {
    float fw, fh;

    // If the width or height of the corner oval is zero, then it reduces to a right angle,
    // so instead of a rounded rectangle we have an ordinary one.
    if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {
        CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
        return;
    }

    //  Save the context's state so that the translate and scale can be undone with a call
    //  to CGContextRestoreGState.
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    //  Translate the origin of the contex to the lower left corner of the rectangle.
    CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));

    //Normalize the scale of the context so that the width and height of the arcs are 1.0
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);

    // Calculate the width and height of the rectangle in the new coordinate system.
    fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;
    fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;

    // CGContextAddArcToPoint adds an arc of a circle to the context's path (creating the rounded
    // corners).  It also adds a line from the path's last point to the begining of the arc, making
    // the sides of the rectangle.
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2);                // Start at lower right corner
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);   // Top right corner
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);     // Top left corner
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);      // Lower left corner
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1);    // Back to lower right

    // Close the path
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    // Restore the context's state. This removes the translation and scaling
    // but leaves the path, since the path is not part of the graphics state.
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: why don't you add  'cornerRadius' to your view's layer and set masksToBounds to YES... that should show rounded corners...

Comment: this is a great post to read, with code - http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: @lukya, yes i can, and i have, but i just wanted to check the issue with this piece of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a simpler formulation using UIKit calls:

```
- (UIImage*) roundCorneredImage: (UIImage*) orig radius:(CGFloat) r {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(orig.size, NO, 0);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, orig.size} 
                                cornerRadius:r] addClip];
    [orig drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, orig.size}];
    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Notice the NO parameter - this makes the image context transparent, so the clipped-out region is transparent.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/detroit-labs/AmazeKit

sounds like a job for a library

Answer (score 1):

Right after creating the bitmap context clear it with:

```
CGContextClearRect (context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h));
```

Answer (score 1):

lukya's comment below your question is what you probably want to do.

Make sure you import QuartzCore:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then, if you have a UIImageView of your image that you want to have rounded corners, just call (assuming imageView is a property and cornerRadius is the desired corner radius):

```
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Since you already have self.CGImage, you could do this to create a UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage]];
```

Just make sure to release the imageView after you add it as a subview.

Answer (score 1):

```
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.height/2;
profileImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Rather than just post bare code, it would help if you added some explanation as to why your solution is best, or how it solves the problem.