# Clip UIImage with UIBezierPath Asynchronously

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiimage, uibezierpath, uigraphicscontext

I want to add rounded corners to an UIImageView without using QuartzCore to avoid performance issues in a UIScrollView so I solved it like that:

```
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(self.cornerRadius, self.cornerRadius)];
    [path addClip];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext( ),kCGBlendModeClear); CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddPath(context,path.CGPath);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextClearRect(context,CGRectMake(0,0,width,height));

    [_image drawInRect:rect];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Sadly, called in drawRect, this takes a little bit of processing time which produces a lag while scrolling in a UIScrollView. Hence I tried to process this in a seperate thread with the help of a dispatch_async. This removed the lag and everything works smoothly like it should be. But now I have another problem. I get many many invalid context messages in the debugger because the GraphicsContext is not always present when the thread starts the image processing asynchronously.
Is there a way to process the rounded corners in my Image without getting invalid context messages? Please note that I do not want to use QuarzCore's cornerRadius or mask-functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing more work than you need to. The "invalid context" messages are caused by calling `[path addClip]` before calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`. The `UIBezierPath` tries to access the thread's current graphics context, but you haven't set one up yet.

Here's a simpler way to get the same results. Note that you don't need to use `CGContext` at all.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(self.cornerRadius, self.cornerRadius)];
[path addClip];

[_image drawInRect:rect];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add rounded corners to an UIImageView without using QuartzCore to avoid performance issues

One approach is to round the corners of the *image* instead of the corners of the UIImageView. See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125604/341994

We start with any UIImage and round its corners by drawing into a clipped context. This takes no "processing time" and causes no performance issues.

(**NOTE:** In a table view or other very fast scrolling or animation situation, there can be performance issues caused by the transparency at the rounded corners. But that is a much more general problem and has little to do without how the rounding is done; it has to do with the fact that we must constantly composite the moving shape onto the background. If the background is a solid color and you know in advance what it will be, it is more efficient to make an *opaque* image where the rounded corner areas have the color of the background.)